# Java Strings to same file but different output

Tags: java, android, string

I'm currently learning java, and want to make an app where the main activity has two buttons in the `main.xml`, `Button 1 = 1 Button 2 = 2`.

If you push any of the buttons I want to go to the same page, but if I push the `button 1` I want a textfield where it says 1 and if you push `button 2` the textfield says 2.

How do I do that?

Here is my current code:

Page 1(MatchMenuTest):

```
    public class MatchMenuTest extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE_LA_HOME = "com.epstudios.basketballmanager_v1.MatchResult";
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE_LA_AWAY = "com.epstudios.basketballmanager_v1.MAtchResult";
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE_SA_HOME = "com.epstudios.basketballmanager_v1.MATCHRESULT";
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE_SA_AWAY = "com.epstudios.basketballmanager_v1.MaTchResult";
Button matchla, matchsa;
String LA, SA;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    matchla.setOnClickListener(this);
    matchsa.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void matches (){
    String SA = "San Antonio";
    String LA = "Lakers";
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.match1:
        Intent matchresult = new Intent(this, MatchResult.class);
        MatchResult.putExtra(MatchMenuTest.EXTRA_MESSAGE_LA_HOME, LA);
        MatchResult.putExtra(MatchMenuTest.EXTRA_MESSAGE_LA_AWAY, LA);
        startActivity(matchresult);
        break;
    case R.id.match2:
        Intent matchresult1 = new Intent(this, MatchResult.class);
        MatchResult.putExtra(MatchMenuTest.EXTRA_MESSAGE_SA_HOME, SA);
        MatchResult.putExtra(MatchMenuTest.EXTRA_MESSAGE_SA_AWAY, SA);
        startActivity(matchresult1);
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Page 2(Match):

```
    public class Match extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE_HOME = "com.epstudios.basketballmanager_v1.MatchResult";
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE_AWAY = "com.epstudios.basketballmanager_v1.MATCHRESULT";
TextView awayGoals, homeGoals, home, away;
Button homebtn, awaybtn, gotoresult;
int homecount, awaycount;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.match);

    baconAndEggs();

    homebtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    awaybtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    gotoresult.setOnClickListener(this);

    String SAAway = getString().getStringExtra(MatchMenuTest.EXTRA_MESSAGE_LA_HOME, -1);
    String LAHome = getString().getStringExtra(MatchMenuTest.EXTRA_MESSAGE_SA_AWAY, -1);
    String SAHome = getString().getStringExtra(MatchMenuTest.EXTRA_MESSAGE_SA_HOME, -1);
    String LAAway = getString().getStringExtra(MatchMenuTest.EXTRA_MESSAGE_LA_AWAY, -1);
}

private void baconAndEggs() {
    awayGoals = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Away);
    homeGoals = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Home);
    homebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.homeBtn);
    awaybtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.awayBtn);
    gotoresult = (Button) findViewById(R.id.matchResult);

}

public void counter() {
    awaycount = 1;
    homecount = 0;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.homeBtn:
        homecount++;
        homeGoals.setText("Lakers: " + homecount);
        break;
    case R.id.awayBtn:
        awaycount++;
        awayGoals.setText("Heat: " + awaycount);
        break;
    case R.id.matchResult:
        Intent result = new Intent(this, MatchResult.class);
        result.putExtra(Match.EXTRA_MESSAGE_AWAY, awaycount);
        result.putExtra(Match.EXTRA_MESSAGE_HOME, homecount);
        startActivity(result);
        break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
 }
```

When I push the matchla i want to change the text "Lakers: " to a the LA_HOME message. And if i push the matchsa the text turns to SA_HOME message.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for a code-writing service.

Comment: First off, don't name your Button 1, that's just asking for trouble. Call it aButton, or something to that effect.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? furthermore, I dont fully understand you.

Comment: It is not so clear. 
From what I understand you want when you press Button1 comes out of a textfield. 

If so please use the Activity textfield and add visibility = false. 
Then you set when you press Button1 changes in visibility true

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want something like this:

main_activity.xml (PS: I omit some width an height settings. You need them for every View, though)

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <Button android:text="button1" android:id="@+id/button1" />
    <Button android:text="button2" android:id="@+id/button2" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/textview" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
        findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textview.setText("1");
            }
        });
        findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textview.setText("2");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

EDIT: considering your requirement, try to implement this piece of code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Match.class);
i.putExtra("home", "lakers");
i.putExtra("away", "san antonio");
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: I want to set the text in another activity

Comment: See edit for extra code